TypeVar defined within if/else
While this code works:
from typing import TypeAlias, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", complex, float, str)

z: TypeAlias = tuple[T, ...] | list[T]

defining T conditionally does not.
from typing import Generic, TypeAlias, TypeVar

try:
    import somepackage
    use_complex = True
except:
    use_complex = False

if use_complex:
    T = TypeVar("T", complex, float, str)
else:
    T = TypeVar("T", float, str)

z: TypeAlias = tuple[T, ...] | list[T]

I am getting: Variable not allowed in type expression
Is there a way to tell the typechecker that use_complex is a constant and therefore it is either one branch or the other, T is defined only once and does not change?

How is the type checker supposed to know whether the import will succeed or fail when the script runs?

It does not need to be resolved when the script runs, but rather for when I am developing against that package.

mypy and Pyright1 both support defining compile-time constants to enable control flow analysis like this; the behaviour is similar to sys.version_info, sys.platform, or typing.TYPE_CHECKING guards.
Put the following in your mypy configuration file:
[mypy]

# Only specify ONE of the following:

# * When developing against the package
always_true = use_complex

# * When not developing against the package
always_false = use_complex

Then do one of the following:

Define the constant in a dedicated module
# constants.py

try:
    import somepackage
    use_complex = True
except:
    use_complex = False

>>> import constants
>>>
>>> if constants.use_complex: ...
...     ...


Define the constant in the same module and use it. This is the same as your example in the question (mypy playground demo: always_true = use_complex, always_false = use_complex)
try:
     import somepackage
     use_complex = True
except:
     use_complex = False

if use_complex:
     T = TypeVar("T", complex, float, str)
else:
     T = TypeVar("T", float, str)

z: TypeAlias = tuple[T, ...] | list[T]

num: z[complex]  = [8j]  # OK when `always_true = use_complex`, else errors when `always_false = use_complex`



During development, you'd just change your configuration file to switch between the use_complex modes.
Note that the try...except doesn't actually do anything for mypy here, that's only for your runtime behaviour.


See the defineConstant configuration of https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md

